# How to plot '%d.%m.%Y %h:%min:%sec' as timestamp with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, timestamp

I am having a hard time to understand how the timestamp in my data can be used for matplotlib.

Here's what my data looks like:

```
Label   Power   Cold_junction   Prof100 Prof200 Prof300 Prof400 Prof600 Prof1000    Temp05      Temp10  Temp20  Temp30  Temp50  Temp100
Units   V   deg C   %   %   %   %   %   %   °C  °C  °C  °C  °C  °C
29.09.2020 11:20:00 10,9    25,4    1,8 4,6 3,5 0,2 #-INF   #-INF   22,9    23,1    23,0    23,2    23,0    23,1
29.09.2020 11:30:00 10,9    25,5    1,8 4,5 3,5 0,1 #-INF   #-INF   23,0    23,2    23,1    23,3    23,2    23,3
29.09.2020 11:40:00 10,9    25,7    1,8 4,5 3,4 0,0 #-INF   #-INF   23,1    23,3    23,2    23,3    23,3    23,4
29.09.2020 11:50:00 10,9    25,8    1,7 4,4 3,4 0,0 #-INF   #-INF   23,2    23,4    23,3    23,5    23,4    23,5
```

so far i know how to import this data into a numpy.ndarray using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
a = np.genfromtxt(r'shortglienig.txt', delimiter=None, skip_header=2, dtype=str, comments=None)
a = np.char.replace(a, ',','.')
a = np.char.replace(a,'\t',' ')
date = a[0:len(a),0]
time = a[0:len(a),1]
prof100 = a[0:len(a), 4]
```

and thats how date, time and the data for prof100 are converted to a variable with the type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Now how do i plot that putting the date and time on the X and the prof100 data on the Y axis?
Thought the next step would be converting the time-data into a format matlplotlib can work with...
I thought mdates.date2num or mdates.datestr2num could be usefull. but is that even making sense?

Comment: If that is not the raw data in the txt file, please repaste the data directly from the txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by converting your `proof100` values to floats. Then you can also concatenate `date` and `time` into a single string that you can use as labels for your x-axis with the `plt.xticks` function. The code then looks like that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

#Loading data
a = np.genfromtxt(r'shortglienig.txt', delimiter=None, skip_header=2, dtype=str, comments=None)
a = np.char.replace(a, ',','.')
a = np.char.replace(a,'\t',' ')


date = a[:,0]
time = a[:,1]

#Concatenating date and time
N_lines=len(date)
date_and_time=[]
[date_and_time.append(date[i]+'_'+time[i]) for i in range(N_lines)]

#Converting proof100 to floats   
proof100=[]
[proof100.append(float(a[i,4])) for i in range(N_lines)]

#Plotting
plt.plot(np.arange(N_lines),proof100)
plt.xlabel('date and time')
plt.ylabel('proof100')

#Setting up date and time as xticks
plt.xticks(np.arange(N_lines), date_and_time,fontsize='8')
plt.show()
```

And the output gives:

[image]